# Opportunities for Science Editing

Tags: copy-editing

I am a graduate of electrical engineering with interests in quantum computing, machine learning and science popularisation. I have been a managing editor for a local science magazine for more than a year and wish to look into some more opportunities for exposure and resume-building. LinkedIn and Google haven't been of much help. How should I look for opportunities in science editing?

Comment: Copy-editing and editing are very different things. Which are you interested in?

Comment: Related: [about academic proof-reading, what to do in this situation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/130099/49593) Although this earlier question asks about what such services are available for someone who wants to use them, it should be relevant to someone interested in employment opportunities with such services.

Comment: I think you will find that scientific editing is usually outsourced to the lowest bidder, which is often in a country with a low cost of living.